# Java: Declare as a parent class, but instantiate as Child, then using the unique method in Child

Tags: java

I ran into this problem because I need to instantiate based on user input.
Considering the following.

```
   public class Parent{
       public void foo(){
         System.out.println("foo");
       }
   }

   public class Child extends Parent{
       public void UniqChildMethod(){
          System.out.println("I am unique")
       }
   }
```

I need to create parent or child based on user input.So lets say if the input is 0. mother object is created, if the input is 1, child is created. Since a bunch of share methods will be call on this object, i dont want to write the same code twice under if/else condition. So my workaround is that, I create a parent object set to null, and instantiate base on user input.

Here is when problem came:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) {
        Parent obj = new Child();

        obj.UniqueChildMethod();   <--- The method is underfined for the type parent
   }
```

is there a workaround for this issue?

Comment: You should read about interfaces first. And then you can apply a _factory pattern_ conditionally instantiating different instances of the same interface. It is probably one of the most commonly used patterns these days.

Comment: @OlegSklyar even with factory method, it will still be writing a lot of repeatitive code. I though Abstract Factory Method will be the right pattern at this case.

Answer (score 0):

If you know your `Parent` is indeed a `Child` object reference, yo can cast it and call child methods:

```
((Child) obj).UniqueChildMethod();
```

In typical app, one should check for object type before class to avoid `ClassCastException`:

```
if (obj instanceof Child) {
   Child childObj = (Child) obj;
   childObj.UniqueChildMethod(); 
}
```

Comment: Even though this looks like using a logic similar to what the OP describes in his question, it is a poor advice as it aims at literally solving the question asked rather than addressing the underlying issue.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `switch` to solve this problem.

```
 public static void main(String argv[]) {
    Parent obj = null;
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    int x = scanner.nextInt();

    switch (x){
        case 0 :    obj = new Parent();
                    obj.foo();
                    break;
        case 1 :    obj = new Child();
                    ((Child) obj).UniqChildMethod();
                    break;
                    default: obj = null;
    }
}
```